# Can't get array after doing exec in php with OOP in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, exec

I'm trying to get values of array using POO. But I want to do it using exec (I have to).

this is my exec.php

```
include('PriceList.php');

for($i=0;$i<1100;$i++){
$tableau[]=$i;
}

$lstPrix = new PriceList($tableau);
exec("php execute.php ");
```

execute.php

```
include('PriceList.php');
call_user_func( 'PriceList::getLstPrix' );
```

and a simple class PriceList.class.php

```
class PriceList
{
    public static $_lstPrix = array();

    public function __construct($lstPrix){  
        self::$_lstPrix = $lstPrix;
    }

    public static function getLstPrix(){        
        return self::$_lstPrix;
    }
}
```

I'm trying to get the values of my array but it doesn't work. Where am I doing wrong? some help pls.

Comment: POO or OOP you should understand...

Comment: @CodeGodie: OOP... but in French!

Comment: `exec` calls a script as a seperate process. That process doesn't have access to the internal state of your current PHP script. I don't know why you would insist on using `exec` becuase it's probably not the right tool.

Comment: oh in French.. :) i understand. just thought it was funny because it sounds like poop.

Comment: haha sorry I forgot to post it in english

Comment: anyway.. this approach will not work. When you use a class it will hold whatever variable you are sending for that specific instance only. I think you are getting confused with the idea of saving the information sent to a database, which is what you should do if you want to access the data sent later on.

Comment: @Halcyon so I can't get my object after an exec? But the object are not saved "tomporarly"?

Comment: @Halcyon is right, this doesn't make sense.

Comment: @sarikaya you can read the output of an `exec` command but the `PriceList` instance in the process you spawn doesn't have `$tableau` as it's data. `getLstPrix()` will return an empty array.

Comment: instead of `exec("php execute.php ");` why cant you just do `$lstPrix->getLstPrix()` ?

Comment: must be an academic exercise

Comment: I'm doing some maintenance in a script (not mine) and there is an exec to another script which is big. And I have to get these values

Answer (score 2):

The problem in your case is that you set your prices in one process.  Then, when the end of the code is reached, your static variable is destroyed.

Then, you launch a new process and try to get the prices.  The static variable is empty as it wasn't persisted in any way and it's not the same process.  That is why you get an empty array.

I know that what you are trying to achieve here would work in some other cases like an ASP.NET website with IIS as long as you use the same Application pool.  If you set the static variable in one request, you can get the value in another request later.

You should save your list somewhere and get it back later.  I would consider a database or maybe serialize the data and store it in a file.

Comment: too bad I can't do that. So if I understand I have to get the exec (script) in the same process

Comment: No, you can only spawn a new process with exec, you can pass another argument to exec and it will return that variable populated with the result of the exec

Comment: ...or save the list somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

For reasons well explained in a previous answer, you simply cannot do that.

However, you should know that while you cannot *share* data between processes, you can *pass* data from the caller processes to the child process, using various tricks (also known as *inter process communication*, or IPC).

## Passing data from caller to child

Here is one simple method, using argv:

*exec.php*

```
$array = range(0,1100);
exec('php execute.php '.json_encode($array));
```

*execute.php*

```
$array = json_decode($argv[1]);
```

Another method, using `stdin`:

*exec.php*

```
$array = range(0,1100);
exec('echo '.json_encode($array).' | php execute.php');
```

*execute.php*

```
$array = json_decode(fgets(STDIN));
```

Note: there might be some escaping needed in some cases, check [escapeshellargs](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.escapeshellarg.php).

Another method on POSIX systems is to use [proc_open](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.proc-open.php) instead of exec, and create a writeable pipe to the child `stdin` and write your data there (check the example in the doc, it's well explained).

## Passing results back

Using `exec`, your child process can just echo JSON, that you can decode in the caller.

With `proc_open`, you need a pipe on `stdout` that the child will write to. Also pretty well explained in the PHP doc.

Comment: I already tried this way like this `escapeshellarg(serialize($lstPrix))` but it can't handle big arrays

Comment: @sarikaya `serialize` is way too verbose. Use `json_encode` for shorter result (the example above works fine).

Comment: It works really fine but sometimes my array is more then 50k rows so when it's really big I have a warning

Comment: anyway I'm going to do all in one process and not do the exec. I don't think I have others choices but thanks

Comment: @sarikaya You have plenty other choices. I edited my answer with another solution for longer strings (using stdin). And in any cases, `proc_open` will always work. Or a temporary file for that matter

Answer (score 0):

Taken into account all the comments above, you should be able to make this work by sending a JSON and returning a JSON.  This is what you can do:

**exec.php:**

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 1100; $i++) {
    $tableau[] = $i;
}

$json = json_encode($tableau);
$returned_json = exec("php execute.php $json");
$returned_array = json_decode($returned_json);

var_dump($returned_array);
```

**execute.php**

```
include('PriceList.php');
$array = json_decode($argv[1]);
$lstPrix = new PriceList($array);
$result = $lstPrix::getLstPrix();
echo json_encode($result);
```

Source about **[$argv](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.argv.php)**